# Transcrypt and Javascript this with jQuery

Tags: jquery, this, transcrypt

I want to translate this sample html doc to Transcrypt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

My code results in hide.py:

```
__pragma__ ('alias', 'S', '$')

def hide():
    S("p").click(S(this).hide())

S(document).ready(hide)
```

When running the hide.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="__javascript__/hide.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> 
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error TypeError: (intermediate value).apply is not a function in the console window.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
S("p").click(S(this).hide())
```

you call hide, rather than pass the address of the hide callback. That is the same problem you encountered here:

[Transcrypt and FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851822/transcrypt-and-filereader)

If I correct that, I get:

```
__pragma__('alias', 'S', '$')

def hide():
   S("p").click(S(this).hide)

S(document).ready(hide)
```

It reports several invalid keyframes.

**If I do the same directly in JavaScript (so without Transcrypt):**

```
function hide () {
   $("p").click($(this).hide);
}

$(document).ready(hide)
```

**I get exactly the same errors.**

I've looked up what the JS code should be here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

namely:

```
function hide () {
    $("p").click(function () {$(this).hide ()});
}

$(document).ready(hide)
```

This is indeed what's in your original HTML inline script.
In Transcrypt that would be:

```
__pragma__('alias', 'S', '$')

def hide():
   S("p").click(lambda: S(this).hide ())

S(document).ready(hide)
```

I've tested both, and the JavaScript as well as the Transcrypt version work fine.

If I look at the code that Transcrypt generates, that's unsurprising:

```
    var hide = function () {
        $ ('p').click ((function __lambda__ () {
            return $ (this).hide ();
        }));
    };
    $ (document).ready (hide);
```

The code generated by Transcrypt resembles the manually written JavaScript like two drops of water.

Don't be confused by the fact that here `hide ()` (with braces) rather than `hide` (without braces) is used. It is the anonymous c.q lambda function that is the callback here, not the `hide` function. And the anonymous c.q. lambda functions aren't called when passed to `click ()`. In other words, they have no trailing braces.

Making the same error on purpose:

```
__pragma__('alias', 'S', '$')

def hide():
   S("p").click((lambda: S(this).hide ())())

S(document).ready(hide)
```

wouldn't work, neither would:

```
function hide () {
    $("p").click((function () {$(this).hide ()}) ());
}

$(document).ready(hide)
```

So the distinction between passing a callback:

```
 $("p").click (my_callback)     // Right
```

and calling it:

```
 $("p").click (my_callback ())  // Wrong
```

is crucial.

I hope this clarifies matters a bit.

You may wonder why you can not simply pass `$(this).hide`, without the extra wrapper function that calls it.

This is because `$(this).hide` does not evaluate to a fixed callback address that can later be used in a call. The encapsulating function, on the other hand, has a fixed address, hence can be used as callback.

This is an example of JQuery magic that is on one hand very clever, on the other hand suggests a simplicity that isn't always there.

*A hint about function naming:
You've named your function `hide`, which kind of fuels the confusion between calling a function and passing its address. Your `hide` does not hide anything. It only installs a callback that can hide something. So the name `install_hide` would probably be more appropriate, though a bit longer...*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. That also answers a question about anonymous functions in Javascript and how this can be translated to Python via lambda. Very good hint.